# Multi Row-Column tableView in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, How can I show the data in tableView as per following image.

[image]

Help me to solve this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: Create a custom table cell. For Mon Tue View Use Header View

Comment: @Divyu,Thanks for your reply.  what about the left side of table view?

Comment: Treat the whole communication row as one cell. Make it Dynamic. I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Divyu, so, Task1, Task2,etc. are what type of controls??

Comment: they are click able or not? If not Take labels otherwise buttons.

Answer (score 4):

You can use collectionView for this purpose.As it is looking like a grid View , so `UICollectionView` will be perfect choice to be used as grid sheet.

You can use the [RFQuiltLayout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout) library, which is a subclass of `UICollectionView`. Here is the code you can use to create your layout:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    RFQuiltLayout* layout = (id)[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout];
    layout.direction = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    layout.blockPixels = CGSizeMake(100, 40);
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 21;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UILabel* label = (id)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    if(!label) label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    label.tag=21;
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [label setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Task%i",indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        label.text=@"Category";
    }

    if (indexPath.row==3) {
        label.text=@"Communication";
    }

    if (indexPath.row==8) {
        label.text=@"Meeting";
    }

    if (indexPath.row==13) {
        label.text=@"Others";
    }

    [cell setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    return insets;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

#pragma mark – RFQuiltLayoutDelegate

- (CGSize) blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row==0)return CGSizeMake(2, 1);
    if (indexPath.row==3) return CGSizeMake(2, 2);
    if (indexPath.row==8) return CGSizeMake(2, 2);
    if (indexPath.row==13) return CGSizeMake(2, 2);

    return CGSizeMake(1, 1);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)insetsForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1 for complete and useful answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display exactly as shown in the figure, ignore my answer.
You can display it using two uitableviews.
First you need to create a tableview with header name **category**
There must be two rows.ie, communication and meeting.
if user selects the communication, then navigates to the second table view
in second table view, header names are Mon,tue,Wed,Thur for each section.
then displays the tasks in each rows.